# Multiple constructors for different arguments in C++

Tags: c++

I'm quite new to C++ and I was wondering if there is any way around duplicating constructors, with variations in the passed arguments.
I need to identify the correct given value (either float or int), check if the float can nicely be casted to an integer (e.g. 1.0) and call another constructor that accepts two integers if my values pass the test.

If anyone as any tips on improving this solution in general that would be great.

```
Fraction(int n, int d) : numerator(n), denominator(d) {
    simplify(n, d);
}

Fraction(float n, float d) {
    if (!isInteger(n) && !isInteger(d)) {
        throw invalid_argument("Fractions only accept real numbers.");
    } else {
        Fraction(int(n), int(d));
    }
}

Fraction(int n, float d) {
    if (!isInteger(n) && !isInteger(d)) {
        throw invalid_argument("Fractions only accept real numbers.");
    } else {
        Fraction(int(n), int(d));
    }
}

Fraction(float n, int d) {
    if (!isInteger(n) && !isInteger(d)) {
        throw invalid_argument("Fractions only accept real numbers.");
    } else {
        Fraction(int(n), int(d));
    }
}
```

Comment: Delegated constructors if your compiler supports them.

Comment: If you only want to support integer values, why do you want an option that takes `float`?

Comment: Your logic is wrong for the conditionals. Also, why are you checking that the arguments are integers? The compiler should do this already. Adding useless messages, and throwing exceptions just makes your code longer.

Comment: Because I want to be able to check if the passed parameter is a decimal. If I initialise my class with Fraction(9, 3.1), my values will be casted to int and thus become 9 and 3 but I want to be able to retrieve the original value of 3.1.

Comment: To clarify: you want to allow , at runtime, a `float` to be passed which does hold an exact integer value?

Comment: Yes. I didn't want the user to be able to use the Class by passing in a float that can't be nicely casted to an int, like 1.0 But saying that, throwing an error on the constructor isn't a nice solution either.

Comment: I down-voted this as a result of these nonsensical statements `if (!isInteger(n) && !isInteger(d))`. This isn't PHP, no need to do things like this.

Comment: I understand your down-vote but I was just trying to show what I was trying to achieve and receive feedback on how to avoid using silly statements, silly constructors etc. As I mentioned earlier I am new to C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could use only the floats ctor and test your parameters.
If you only have two ctors one for ints and one for floats, then only if both numbers are int the ints ctor will be called. otherwise the floats ctor will be called.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I'm just going to stick with the first constructor, without doing any checks on the data type.

Comment: You can also use only the floats ctor and always check your parameters. Whatever suits you best :)